# Is it possible that Qui-Gon let Darth Maul kill him?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

Is it possible that because of his certainty that Anakin was the chosen one, and his knowledge that the Council had decided that Anakin was too old for training and too full of fear, Qui-Gon let himself die? His death led to the Council's changing its mind about Anakin.

Would Anakin have been trained anyway even if Qui-Gon had survived along with Obi-Wan?

There don't seem to be any clues in the movies, but I'm wondering if anyone shares this opinion or has any evidence.

Comment: Is it *possible*? Of course. Whether he *did* or not is the real question.

Comment: You're describing a Jedi master committing suicide. That's the dumbest thing I ever heard. If you have eyes, you saw Qui Gon was shocked as hell about losing the fight of his life.

Comment: I don't know if he did - but that's actually a theory I've heard almost since the movie first came out.

Comment: @Harry Wait until you find out what happened to Obi-Wan.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**According to the official novelisations, there's no special indication that Qui-Gon deliberately allowed himself to be killed.**

In the Junior Novelisation, it's noted that Qui-Gon Jinn was fighting as hard as Obi-Wan has ever seen. Given the number of conflicts they've been in, we can assume that this is pretty darned hard:

> *The Sith Lord wasn’t wearing a helmet; it was only the light of the
>   laser walls on the black of his tattoo. And **Qui-Gon was fighting more
>   fiercely than Obi-Wan had ever seen him fight before.** Yet the feeling
>   persisted: That should be me out there, not Qui-Gon. Obi-Wan shook his
>   head again. Won’t these laser walls ever come down again?* - <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Phantom Menace: Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

In the main novelisation, the omniscient narrator makes it pretty clear that Qui-Gon is trying very strongly to kill Maul:

> Qui-Gon pressed hard in the beginning, **sensing how dangerous this
>   man was, wanting to put an end to the combat quickly.Long hair flying
>   out behind him, he attacked with ferocity and determination.** Obi-Wan
>   came with him, following his lead. They had fought together before,
>   and they knew each other’s moves. Qui-Gon had trained Obi-Wan, and
>   while the younger Jedi was not yet his equal, he believed that one day
>   Obi-Wan would be better than he had ever been.
>
> So **they challenged the Sith Lord quickly, and just as quickly
>   discovered that their best efforts were not good enough to achieve an
>   early resolution.** They settled into a pattern then, working as a
>   team against their enemy, waiting for an opening. But the Sith Lord
>   was too smart to give them one, and so the battle had gone on. <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Phantom Menace: Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace_(novel))</sup></sub>

Answer (score 8):

Although this question may be closed for being opinion-based, I have to say that I (respectfully) don't agree with the OP; though there is no evidence one way or the other that I could find, here is why:

- Although Qui-gon did receive force visions you could just as easily ask why he didn't also see the almighty mess that came about from his death, including how useful he would have been, as a strong practitioner of the Living Force, in combating Palpatine/the Separatists in the Clone Wars.
- Qui-gon was extremely adept at [the Living Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Living_Force), which discourages looking into/focusing on the future. At the beginning of TPM, Qui-gon mentions this to Obi-wan during the failed negotiations with the Trade Federation during the blockade-cum-invasion of Naboo, and he also analogises it when explaining midi-chlorians to Anakin later on, on Coruscant, as below.

> Obi-wan: I have a bad feeling about this.
>
> Qui-gon Jinn: I don't sense anything.
>
> O: It's not about the mission, Master. It's something ... elsewere,
>   elusive.
>
> Q: Don't center on your anxieties Obi-wan, keep your concentration
>   here and now, where it belongs.
>
> O: But Master, Yoda said I should be mindful of the future.
>
> Q: But not at the expense of the moment. **Be mindful of the Living
>   Force, young Padawan**.
>
> O: Yes, Master.

and

> Anakin: Master, sir ... I heard Yoda talking about midi-chlorians,
>   I've been wondering ... what are midi-chlorians?
>
> Qui-gon: Midi-chlorians are a microscopic life-form that resides
>   within all living cells.
>
> A: They live inside of me?
>
> Q: Inside your cells, yes. And we are symbionts with them.
>
> A: Symbionts?
>
> Q: Life-forms, living together for mutual advantage. Without the
>   midi-chlorians, life could not exist, and we would have no knowledge
>   of the Force. **They continually speak to us, telling us the will of
>   the Force.** When you learn to quiet your mind, you will hear them
>   speaking to you.

- Even though he was [a superb swordsman](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Qui-Gon_Jinn#Lightsaber_combat), Jinn was no match for Maul and [his style didn't work in the environment he was fighting in](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10685/why-did-qui-gon-advance-against-darth-maul-without-obi-wan?rq=1) so his death at Maul's hands isn't, on its own, considered suspect.
- While Jinn had already learned the secret of the Whills as to [retaining his consciousness in the force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_ghost#Rediscovery), why would he prefer to interact indirectly, as he then had to, rather than doing what he threatened to do earlier in TPM; mainly, to disobey the Council and train Anakin anyway. Qui-gon was considered something of a [Gray Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gray_Jedi), so that would not have been outside his character.

> Obi-wan: The boy will not pass the Council's tests, Master. He is far
>   too old.
>
> Qui-gon: Anakin will become a Jedi, I promise you.
>
> O: Don't defy the Council, Master, not again.
>
> Q: I will do what I must, Obi-wan.
>
> O: If you would just follow the code, you would be on the Council.
>   They will not go along with you this time.
>
> Q: You still have much to learn, my young apprentice.

- As it is, Qui-gon didn't [succeed in influencing Anakin after the fact](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Qui-Gon_Jinn#Legacy).
- Qui-gon did bring himself in tune with the Force right before he died, when he meditated inbetween the shields during his fight with Maul, but that would more likely mean bringing himself into the moment, rather than looking into the future.

But as I said, there is no evidence about his motivations that I could find.